# Composite of uniform distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

If $X_1$ is uniform $(0,1)$ and
$X_2$ is uniform $(0, X_1+1)$,
what is $X_3$, which is characterized as uniform $(0, X_2+1)$?

I simulated $X_3$ and got the following graph but found it hard to compute the precise distribution: [image]

Comment: $P[X_3\leq x]=\int^1_0\frac{1}{1+x_1}\int^{x_1 +1}_0\frac{1}{1+x_2}\int^{x\wedge (x_2+1)}_0\,dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1$

Comment: Can you illustrate why you write down an equation like this? And what is $x \cap (x_2+1)$

Comment: $a\wedge b=\min(a, b)$. The trick is to use conditional expectation. It is not difficult see that the distribution of $X_3$ is supported in the interval $[0,3]$. So it is enough to consider $0\leq x\leq3$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P[X_3\leq x]=\int^1_0\frac{1}{1+x_1}\int^{x_1+1}_0\frac{1}{1+x_2}\int^{x\wedge (x_2+1)}_0\,dx_3\,dx_2\,dx_1$

To see this, notice that
$$P[X_3\leq z|X_2]=\frac{1}{1+X_2}\int^{x\wedge(X_2+1)}_0\,du$$
and
$$ P[X_2\leq y|X_1]=\frac{1}{1+X_1}\int^{y\wedge(X_1+1)}_0\,dt$$
Hence,for any bounded measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$
$$E[f(X_2)|X_1]=\frac{1}{1+X_1}\int^{1+X_1}_0f(t)\,dt$$